# Refresh tableLayout

Tags: android

Hi I have a tableLayout and am populating the layout with ImageView[][] using a nested for loop. I'm currently trying to click on an ImageView and rearrange the ImageView[][] data then refresh the screen to reflect the rearrangement. Is there a way to do this? Apparently I can't call the setContentView more than once.

Edit: you can see this is the code for the onclick event. I setContentView of the original TableLayout ('tl') in the onCreate event and can't call it again here.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){
    case 1: 
        image_array = switchTile(image_array, 2,1,0,0);
        Toast.makeText(this, "1 clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    tl.removeAllViewsInLayout();

    for(int i = 0; i < level; i++){
        TableRow new_tr = new TableRow(this);
        new_tr.setLayoutParams(layout_image);

        for(int j = 0; j< level; j++){
            new_tr.addView(image_array[i][j]);
        }
        tl.addView(new_tr);
    }

    tl.invalidate();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this: tableindex.removeAllViews();

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is move the images around, you can just do setImageBitmap () operations on the existing ImageViews.  You can use the same bitmaps and display them on whichever ImageViews you please.